# Find missing files in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am re-arranging files in my file system for my Xcode projects. Therefore, when I open the Xcode project, all of the files are red.

I can add each file manually, but is there a way for Xcode to quickly find these files for me? All of the files are located in one directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Xcode doesn't have a way to automatically locate moved files. You can reconnect a reference to its file using the Inspector (panel on the right) but it is somewhat tedious to do so. In your case, it would probably be faster to simply delete the references and then add the files back to your project.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a bunch of missing (red) files that now live in the same directory, you can improve on the "fix each path individually in the inspector" method by selecting (Cmd-click) all the files at once. You'll see "multiple values" in the inspector, like so:

[image: Xcode screenshot: Multiple Values]

Clicking the button under the Location dropdown will bring up a directory selector -- note that the prompt says "Choose folder containing..." rather than "Choose file and location".

[image]

Comment: All of the original poster's files were in one folder. This method is much faster than the one-by-one method.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answers already given. In a real pinch, or as a last resort, you can open the project file in a text editor and fix the path references by hand.

1. Close the project in Xcode
2. Backup the project file someplace safe
3. In the Finder, right-click on the project file and select "Show Package Contents"
4. Drag project.pbxproj to BBEdit (or TextEdit or whatever)
5. Edit whatever "path = xxx" references you want

Answer (score 0):

In this case i do this steps:

> 1) Add a new group with name Res
>
> 2) Click "Add Files to ..."
>
> 3) Find a folder with resources, and click CMD + A
>
> 4) Set check box on "Create folder references for any added folders".
>   And in source code i use e.g. "fonts/font1.xml".
>
> 5) Then for refresh, i just Removing a Res group references
>
> 6) And do steps from 1 to 4

Hope this will be a useful